# Make computer think a key is pressed on click

Tags: javascript, events, button, key, output

So what i'm looking for is when you press a button or a link the output is that the computer thinks that you've pressed the spacebar.

Comment: this is different on every operating system, an every programming language.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in javascript. What are you trying to accomplish with this? It would be insecure for the browser to have control over your mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify any **language** or **OS** but with `c#` you can use:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

---

[How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

With `jQuery` you can simulate a key press (spacebar / 32) with:

```
<button id="test">Test ME</button>
```

---

```
$('#test').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 32}));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, in javascript.

Comment: @PedroLobito link doesn't work

Comment: @WalterM corrected, thank you.